# Exoplayer E/BufferQueueProducer: [MediaCodec.release](id:1b20000006c,api:0,p:-1,c:434) detachBuffer: BufferQueue has no connected producer

Tags: android, react-native, exoplayer, react-native-video

I am using react-native-video. In list of videos randomly some errors related to buffer occur, here is android studio logcat:

```
2023-07-31 10:09:11.516 434-434/com.myprj E/ExoPlayer Exception: com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
2023-07-31 10:09:11.517 434-434/com.myprj D/ReactExoplayerView: onStateChanged: playWhenReady=true, playbackState=idle
2023-07-31 10:09:11.517 434-1232/com.myprj I/ReactNativeJS: '==>VIDEO NOT LOADED', { error: 
       { error: 
          { errorException: 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error',
            errorString: 'Unrecognized media format' } } }
2023-07-31 10:09:11.518 434-12385/com.myprj I/hw-BpHwBinder: onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients
2023-07-31 10:09:11.521 434-12385/com.myprj D/MediaCodec: flushMediametrics
2023-07-31 10:09:11.521 434-12385/com.myprj D/MediaCodec: flushMediametrics
2023-07-31 10:09:11.525 434-12381/com.myprj I/hw-BpHwBinder: onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients
2023-07-31 10:09:11.526 434-8306/com.myprj E/BufferQueueProducer: [MediaCodec.release](id:1b20000006c,api:3,p:434,c:434) detachBuffer: slot 0 is not owned by the producer (state = FREE)
2023-07-31 10:09:11.526 434-8306/com.myprj E/BufferQueueProducer: [MediaCodec.release](id:1b20000006c,api:3,p:434,c:434) detachBuffer: slot 1 is not owned by the producer (state = FREE)
2023-07-31 10:09:11.526 434-12380/com.myprj D/SurfaceUtils: disconnecting from surface 0xb400006f97930520, reason disconnectFromSurface
2023-07-31 10:09:11.526 434-8306/com.myprj E/BufferQueueProducer: [MediaCodec.release](id:1b20000006c,api:0,p:-1,c:434) detachBuffer: BufferQueue has no connected producer
2023-07-31 10:09:11.526 434-12380/com.myprj D/MediaCodec: flushMediametrics
2023-07-31 10:09:11.527 434-12380/com.myprj D/MediaCodec: flushMediametrics
2023-07-31 10:09:15.470 434-8305/com.myprj D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0: evictor expired: 4, evicted: 0
2023-07-31 10:09:17.472 434-8305/com.myprj D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0: bufferpool2 0xb400006ef7f35508 : 0(0 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 0/4 (recycle/alloc) - 3/4 (fetch/transfer)
2023-07-31 10:09:17.472 434-8305/com.myprj D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0: bufferpool2 0xb400006ef7ec21f8 : 0(0 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 1/6 (recycle/alloc) - 2/4 (fetch/transfer)
2023-07-31 10:09:17.472 434-8305/com.myprj D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0: evictor expired: 2, evicted: 2
```

and if I exit the app and again want to play that video again, it will. I don't know what is the problem, and here is my player code:

```
<Video
            ref={inlineVideoRef}
            source={fullVideoPath}
            style={styles.video}
            resizeMode={isFullScreen ? 'contain' : 'cover'}
            onProgress={onDoProgress}
            onLoad={onLoadData}
            controls
            onEnd={onEndTriggered}
            volume={1}
            muted={isMuted}
            repeat={repeat}
            paused={paused || !play || !isFocused}
            posterResizeMode="cover"
            onError={onHandleError}
            poster={getFullImageUrl(poster)}
            onLoadStart={onLoadStart}
            fullscreen={isFullScreen}
          />
```